# Is this the right way to "publish" msg to the topic?

Tags: python, python-3.6, ros, rospy

Currently learning ROS with LGSVL Simulator. I want to publish to "/move_base_simple/goal" topic.

In main code just showing important "import" and the end of the code

```
import rospy
import roslibpy
from rospy import rostime

import lgsvl
import logging

from environs import Env
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

import publisher

### LGSVL SETUP ###
...
###################
ego.set_destination(publisher.GoalPublisher.publish_2d_nav_goal(self=publisher.GoalPublisher,pose_x=9425.16015625, pose_y=9823.15527344, pose_z=0.0))
  
ros = roslibpy.Ros(host='localhost', port=9090) 
ros.run()

sim.run()
```

This is my publisher

```
import rospy
import rospkg
import std_msgs
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseStamped

class GoalPublisher():
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.init_node('webapp', disable_signals=True)
        self.goal_publisher = rospy.Publisher("move_base_simple/goal", PoseStamped, queue_size=10)

    def publish_2d_nav_goal(self, pose_x, pose_y, pose_z):
        goal = PoseStamped()

        goal.header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
        goal.header.frame_id = "map"

        goal.pose.position.x = pose_x
        goal.pose.position.y = pose_y
        goal.pose.position.z = pose_z

        goal.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
        goal.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
        goal.pose.orientation.z = -0.663932738254
        goal.pose.orientation.w = 0.747792296747

        self.goal_publisher.publish(goal)
```

When i am trying to start my main code, i get this error:**rospy.exceptions.ROSInitException: time is not initialized. Have you called init_node()?**

Do i need to add "rospy.init_node(...)" in the main code ? Or how can i fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `rospy.init_node()` for every ros node you create. You can call it wherever you want in the node, however, it *must* be called before trying to use anything in the ros api. In this example your publisher is fine but you're calling `roslibpy.Ros()` before initializing the main code as it's own node.

```
rospy.init_node('main_node')

ego.set_destination(publisher.GoalPublisher.publish_2d_nav_goal(self=publisher.GoalPublisher,pose_x=9425.16015625, pose_y=9823.15527344, pose_z=0.0))
  
ros = roslibpy.Ros(host='localhost', port=9090) 
ros.run()

sim.run()
```